# Parallel Matrix Multiplication in C++

Tags: parallel-processing, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to implement Parallel Multi-threaded Matrix multiplication in C++. The method i follow involves dividing Arrays into 4 sub-arrays and carry out parallel Multiplication using 4 threads on these 4 sub arrays.

I have written a C++ code but it is throwing error and terminates explicitly. Error :
"terminate called after throwing an instance of std::system_error
what():invalid Argument"

Here is my complete code. I am relatively new to C++ and multi-threading.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

#define N 4
using namespace std;
mutex mu;

void stage_1_multiply(int *a,int *b,int *d){
int *xij;
int *yij;
int *zij;
int COLS = N,ROWS = N;
cout<< " thread "<< this_thread::get_id() << " "<<endl;

    for(int i = 0;i<(N/2);++i){
        for(int j = 0;j < (N/2); j++){
                for(int k = 0; k<(N/2);k++){
                        mu.lock();
                        xij = a + ((COLS * i) + k);
                        yij = b + ((COLS * k) + j);
                        zij = d + ((COLS * i) + j);
                        *zij += ( (*xij) * (*yij) );
                        mu.unlock();
                }
        }
    }
}


int main(){
int A[4][4],B[4][4],C[4][4],D_1[4][4],D_2[4][4];

for(int i = 0;i<4;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<4;j++){
            A[i][j] = i + 1;
            B[i][j] = i + 1;
            C[i][j] = 0;
            D_1[i][j] = 0;
            D_2[i][j] = 0;
        }
}
for(int i = 0;i<4;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j< 4;j++){
            cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        }
     cout << endl;
}
for(int i = 0;i<4;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j< 4;j++){
            cout << B[i][j] << " ";
        }
     cout << endl;
}

vector< thread> threads(8);
int th = 0;
threads[th++] = thread(stage_1_multiply,&A[0][0],&B[0][0],&D_1[0][0]);
threads[th++] = thread(stage_1_multiply,&A[0][2],&B[2][0],&D_2[0][0]);
threads[th++] = thread(stage_1_multiply,&A[2][0],&B[0][2],&D_1[2][2]);
threads[th++] = thread(stage_1_multiply,&A[2][2],&B[2][2],&D_2[2][2]);
for( auto& t : threads){
        t.join();
}
threads[th++] = thread(stage_1_multiply,&A[0][0],&B[0][2],&D_1[0][2]);
threads[th++] = thread(stage_1_multiply,&A[0][2],&B[2][2],&D_2[0][2]);
threads[th++] = thread(stage_1_multiply,&A[2][0],&B[0][0],&D_1[2][0]);
threads[th++] = thread(stage_1_multiply,&A[2][2],&B[2][0],&D_2[2][0]);

for( auto& t : threads){
        t.join();
}

// code to add The Matrices D_1 and D_2 goes here. 
for(int i = 0;i<4;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j< 4;j++){
            cout << D_1[i][j] << " ";
        }
     cout << endl;
}
cout << " Main Close "<<endl;
return 0;

}
```

What am doing wrong? is it anything related to parallel access of shared memory? If so how can i correct it?

PS: This is a homework Assignment.

Comment: Posting links to images is not a good idea. At least have them inline or better still have the text

Comment: @EdHeal Sorry about that. This was my first post.